# Does the word "leniency" fit in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-in-context

I am writing a request to my manager and have drafted the last two sentences as follows:

> I trust in god and his judgement, and I trust that virtue lies in his bestowal and his prevention, and that is what encouraged me to write to you. May it finds your support and leniency.

I am wondering if *leniency* is a good word to use in this context. My purpose is to politely and somewhat deferentially appeal to the recipient's kindness, compassion, moral sense, etc.

This is not a question about whether it's appropriate to refer to "God," etc., in the social context, nor for strategic advice.

I wonder if *kind-heartedness* or another term might better express what I intend?

Comment: You need to specify where you are as in my country (UK) the whole thing sounds really, really strange.

Comment: @mdewey I am currently working in the UAE, and I am not a native English speaker (neither the manager to the best of my knowledge). But what part of it do you think is strange?

Comment: It would be very odd to invoke the name of God in a business email. A person is _lenient_ when they punish someone less severely than might have been expected, so _leniency_ is not the word you want here.

Comment: I don't know what is usual in Muslim countries, but in most contexts it would be unprofessional to express a request in such an emotional manner. Something like "I hope you will consider my request" would be quite sufficient.

Comment: @Kate I have seen comments online to the effect that OP's invocation of God is relatively common in everyday communication in some countries in Africa.

Comment: @KateBunting What led you to assume that the OP wanted or could benefit from guidance on what is "professional" or how to appropriately express emotions? This isn't an accusation or a moral rebuke. In fact, I suppose I probably understand the answer by my own set of reactions.  Just ... at least sometimes ... "I don't know what's usual in your context" followed by unsolicited evaluative statements, will not result in effecting the kind of help we (sincerely) want to extend.

Comment: In the UK, using the words God and leniency might be appropriate if you were under a threat of execution by your manager... otherwise no. I understand that it is perfectly normal to invoke the name of Allah routinely in arab countries. Somehow using the word Allah rather than God seems more appropriate to me. But leniency definitely needs to go- unless your manager really is going to kill you. What exactly are you asking for from your manager?

Comment: @Jav Definitely needs to go? Based on what evidence? https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=lenient

Comment: @JimReynolds see my answer

Comment: Why the close votes, folks? The question specifically asks about the appropriateness of the word leniency, which IMHO is not a request for proofreading. It does also ask for suggestions for alternatives, but that's not 'improving phrasing'... it's still a specific request about a specific word in the text.

Comment: @Jav It's a good answer. I didn't suggest that it was the best word. On the other hand, dictionaries are often less complete than we tend to give them credit for. Suppose that the OP is asking for some kind of special attention. In some cultures, it's almost required that "troubling someone" be positioned as a transgression, especially vis-a-vis someone in a "higher status." Sometimes a word or phrase is especially effective precisely because it's not used in the most common sense.

Comment: @Jav That same dictionary doesn't list the positive, "playful" definition of (silly)[https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/silly] that is very commonly used. Only in the past few years did the meaning for *sarcasm* include (basically) "saying the opposite of what's meant, often for a fun and/or 'positive" humorous effect,' appear in any major dictionary. (Oxford, here)[https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sarcasm?q=sarcasm] remains behind on that issue. Most importantly, there are many varieties of English, and communication, as you well know--not 2/

Comment: @Jav pretending to lecture you--occurs in multifactorial ecosystems. I get that it can be a valid statement--perhaps the best when not writing an essay. But "technically" would say that "has to go" could admit to some legitimate exploration. 3/

Comment: @JimReynolds - The OP asked why the first comment described the paragraph as 'really strange', so I tried to explain why it seemed so to a 'Westerner'  It was the OP who raised the question of its being unprofessional; I explained that it would be inappropriate in my culture, but might well be different in theirs. And I had already explained why _lenient_ was the wrong word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We normally capitalize "God" in English, when we are talking about god in a monothesistic religion such as Christianity or Islam.

*Find* should be singular: may it find ... .

We do not know what kind of request or favor you asked.

We do not know if you have a cultural question, but it seems not. If the person you are writing to shares your culture, I think you can trust your natural feeling about how they will interpret the message.

Sometimes, when people write to bosses or "seniors" in English, there is a cultural difference, either related to ethnicity, "business" culture, or both.

I suppose that you have looked up these words, such as *leniency* and some synonyms.

In the “major” Standard Englishes, we do sometimes use *lenient* in the situation such as, "I did something wrong. I hope or trust that you will not punish or treat me too harshly."

However, it can also more generally mean "to be not too strict,” to be more compassionate and more flexible, less harsh, less rigid or more permissive with respect to setting or enforcing rules or expectations. And, if you are writing to someone of higher status, and you want to show respect for that status, then "leniency" might be quite a good word, because it suggests that you show respect for the person's position and their authority to decide.

If you are writing to someone from a very different background, then you should probably add some information to your question about that. People who use this site are from all around the world, so some of us will have different reactions and opinions.

If I don't know anything else, I suppose that "leniency" might be a great word, because it came into your mind, or you found it and chose it based on your background and experience. If the person you are writing to is from a simliar background and experience, then the chance is quite high that they will understand it as you meant it.

You can probably choose the best word based on your feelings. Kindness. Compassion. Grace. Wise consideration. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

The examples  of leniency in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lenient) refer only to criminal matters, so unless you have done something illegal, or your manager has meted out a punishment that is far harsher than would be legal in the UK, it's probably much stronger than you require. Without knowing what you are asking for from your manager, it is impossible suggest a suitable alternative.

This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lenient%20judges%2Clenient%20managers&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clenient%20judges%3B%2Cc0) shows that leniency is often used in relation to judges, and never in relation to managers.

Comment: ![lenient+boss](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18SsgPxuGzmHQZN_EdfTpTg4IFqyLfmzo/view?usp=sharing)

https://www.english-corpora.org/iweb

Comment: @JimReynolds https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lenient+judge%2C+lenient+boss&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clenient%20judge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clenient%20boss%3B%2Cc0 plus manager and boss are in different registers.

Comment: The point being, not bound to "criminal," nor "legal".